# xcode 4.6.2 importing xcode 3 project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I finally upgraded to Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.6.2 but after copying over an old app (xcode 3.5) I get an error when I build. "Codesign error: the entitlements file .... is missing.
The path isn't valid any more, it must be a throwback to the old machine. But I can't figure out how to fix the problem.

I removed the entitlements file and cleaned the project but that didn't help.
Also the app file listed under Products is red and I can't double click on it. Have I missed some important step in importing the project?

Thanks,

EDIT:
Solved the issue finally. I expanded the .xcodeproj package and opened project.pbxproj. Searching for the incorrect path and removing it fixed the issue.

Comment: You can answer your own questions and is recommended that you do so if you find the answer yourself. You will have to wait 1 day however to accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue finally. I expanded the .xcodeproj package and opened project.pbxproj. Searching for the incorrect path and removing it fixed the issue.